# Failed to deploy application to jboss v7.4, logs says "address already in use"

Tags: jboss7.x

I get "address already in use" exception in logs while am trying to deploy the application to jboss7.4 version. Application was failing to deploy. How can i resolve this?

```
15:29:26,241 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] [] [] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "native-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.remoting.server.management" => "WFLYRMT0004: Address already in use 0.0.0.0:10499
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use"}}
15:29:26,263 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] [] [] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:10490"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.remoting.remoting-http-upgrade-service.http-management is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.http-management]"]
}
15:29:26,272 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] [] [] WFLYCTL0459: Triggering roll back due to missing management services.
15:29:26,272 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] [] [] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "native-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.remoting.server.management" => "WFLYRMT0004: Address already in use 0.0.0.0:10499
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use"}}
```

Comment: First of all, you must identify which services are using the ports in question.

Comment: I found out the PID of applications that were using those ports and used kill -9 PID. It worked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the PID of applications that were using those ports and used kill -9 PID. It worked.